# How to find parameters that minimize the sum of squares, using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, systems-of-equations, svd, least-squares

I have a system of linear equations in the following form.
How can I solve it in Matlab?

$$\operatorname*{argmin}_{a,b} \sum_{i,j} [X(i,j)-a\times Y(i,j)-b]^2$$

Where X and Y are known.
I need to estimate a and b - which do not depend on (i,j).

Comment: The solution is $a=b=c=0$. You don't have to use anything to calculate it. I suspect you have an error in your setting.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have modified the function.

Comment: Your expression doesn't depend on $a$.

Comment: sorry. modified again.

Comment: Now it doesn't depend on $c$.

Comment: Then you have the standard least square problem $\min ||x-Ay||^2$ where $x$ is the vector of $X(i,j)$, $A$ is 2 column matrix. The first column consists of $1$s the second column consists of values of $Y(i,j)$. $y=(b,a)$. I cannot believe matlab  does not have a function for least square problem.

Comment: Ya agree. Now it became the standard problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}Y(1,1) & 1 \\ Y(2,1) & 1 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ Y(m,n) & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $y =  \begin{bmatrix}X(1,1) \\ X(2,1)\\ \vdots \\ X(m,n)\end{bmatrix}$, and $x = \begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\end{bmatrix}$.

Then, the problem can be rewritten as $\text{argmin}_{x}\|y-Ax\|_2^2$.

This is now the standard [linear least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)) problem. The solution is $\hat{x} = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty$.

Comment: in MATLAB notation, it would be `A\y`.